# Automaticly insert phrase (Ubuntu 23.04 using Wayland)

Tags: gnome, email, wayland, 23.04, autokey

Trying to switch over from Windows to Ubuntu and have pretty much everything working so that I can do my work on it which is awesome. The only thing I am not able to solve is to be able to easily insert my mail signature without the need to manually type it all in each e-mail.

When I was on windows I was using phraseexpress(.com) which works like a charm, while searching around I found Autokey as an alternative but also found it does not work if you use Wayland for the display. I even tried X11 but was not able to get it to work there either and I would prefer to use Wayland.

So is there no other application or workaround to be able to get my 10 line e-mail signature by simply inputting ",sig" or something like what I had on Windows?

Comment: Which email client are you actually using ?  Most of them support configuring a signature. (without the need of an external app)

Comment: Thunderbird currently, exchange account. I do however need 3 signatures as we have customers around the world and based on the country we use 1 of the 3 signatures

Comment: We also use Freshdesk (support ticket system) on the web and the need for those 3 signatures there is also needed, using Firefox currently

Comment: Is this something for you?: [Multiple signature files for one account](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1172231#answer-998589)   (Which makes this question pretty off-topic here, see:  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Many Email clientsn use `$HOME/.signature`, but YMMV, check the documentation for your particular email client.

Comment: Browsing the Thunderbird Add-Ons (Thunderbird --> Tools --> Add ons and themes) shows no fewer than 13 different signature-related add-ons available. Several look like exactly what you are asking for. If you are saying that none of them can be adapted to work for you, then it's likely that your question is not clear enough about your needs.

Comment: Ok so I wil have a look at the addons, i am sure one of those will work thanks for info!
Still need to be able to do this in a browser too though

Comment: I wonder if a fancy clipboard manager would work for your apparent multi-application-paste needs. [Gnome Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org) has several to choose from that might work.

Comment: I will have a look, found https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-SE/firefox/addon/auto-text-expander/ which seems to do the trick for the browser for now

Answer (score -1):

I definitely recommend Text Blaze (blaze.today) for this. I use it to automate emails and it's a lifesaver

Comment: Some words on how to install it would be helpful.